# Submit a form without clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, html4

```
<form class="myform" action="mail.php">
Your name:<br>
<input type="text" name="myform-name"><br><br>
Your file:<br>
<input type="file" name="myform-file"><br><br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How do I submit this form using vanilla javascript (not jQuery) directly from the code (without user interaction)?

Comment: first things first.. correct: <form class="myform" action="mail.php">

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit()`

Comment: In a comment you say: “I want to paste this form into an iframe and force a hidden submit”. You should say such things in the question itself and clarify them by showing a relevant part of the current code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit()
```

Comment: This will submit a form and reaload a page?

Comment: You want to use AJAX?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a form name in your code:

```
<form name="myform" class="myform" action="mail.php">
Your name:<br>
<input type="text" name="myform-name"><br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

submit the from from javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.myform.submit();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
document.getElementById("my_form_id").submit();
```

Docs [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)

Comment: and where exactly is my_form_id ?

Comment: ARE YOU SURE this works in every browser (I'm speaking about submit function)?

Comment: @Jasper Yes. It is common js functionality you can check it here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Comment: Add the attribute `id="my_form_id"` in your form tag.  `<form class="myform" action="mail.php" id="my_form_id">`